# Is there a standard way to add to the "start menu" on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, installation, qt-installer

I am creating a Linux installer (currently looking at the Qt Installer Framework) and I need to add shortcuts to the start / applications menu.

I have read about and experimented with .desktop files but that just puts the shortcut in the general applications section... How can I create a Vendor/Product/Application structure in the menu?

We are trying to move away from InstallJammer which does this, but as far as I am aware we need to use a custom script in Qt Installer Framework.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: What linux desktop has a vendor/product/application structure?

Comment: .desktop files are the standard for all the unix desktops now. http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: What DE are you targeting? Each uses different mechanism to structure the menu.

Comment: I have got something working in theory using a combination of .directory and .desktop files which appear to be behaving in the same way as InstallJammer. However, at the end of my installer I am calling xdg-desktop-menu install... but it is not having any affect. If I run manually or restart it is fine. Any ideas?